# Doctrine2 Join SUM

Tags: php, design-patterns, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to do this in Doctrine 2.

I have Account entity which have OneToMany to Transaction entity. I need to SUM all values from Transaction filtered by account. Is like this in SQL: `SELECT a.*, SUM(t.amount) AS balance FROM account a INNER JOIN transaction t ON t.account_id = a.id`

### Method #1:

Directly on Entity

```
class Account {
    // some other definitions

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Transaction", mappedBy="account")
     */
    private $transactions;

    public function getBalance() {
        $balance = 0;
        foreach ($this->transactions as $transaction){
            $balance += $transaction->getAmount();
        }
        return $balance;
    }
}
```

I think this is the worst way, since it fetches all related transactions to get their amount.

### Method #2:

Using Repositories

```
class TransactionRepository {
    public function getBalanceByAccount(Account $account){
        $query = $this->em->createQuery("SELECT SUM(t.amount) FROM Transaction t INNER JOIN t.Account a WHERE a.id = ?");
        // ...
        return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
}
```

I'm not pretty sure if it goes on TransactionRepository or AccountRepository.

### Method #3:

Using Service pattern

```
class TransactionService {
    public function getBalanceByAccountId($accountId){
        $query = $this->em->createQuery("SELECT SUM(t.amount) FROM Transaction t INNER JOIN t.Account a WHERE a.id = ?");
        // ...
        return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
}
```

Again, I'm not sure if it goes on TransactionService or AccountService.

### Method #4: (by [Guilherme Blanco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9894372/430989))

Table denormalization, saving balance into account table/Entity.

### Method #n:

Please let me know your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Remember that not all the times you can have a fully normalized Database.
This is a situation where I'd recommend a denormalization, having a balance in your Account entity.

Then, whenever you are saving, just remember that all new Transactions should be sum'ed to the balance and update the balance value at the end.

By doing this, you never need to generate a SUM(), which is way better for your application.

Comment: Surely it will be less expensive to entire application, but I have to do this SUM to populate the balance into account. Where I have to put this code? Use EntityManager::createQuery() (like Method #3) inside the AccountService?

Comment: You can do that in AccountService, since you are managing the Account entity. But the query that retrieves the SUM is part of TransactionService, since it acts over Transactions.